# Dynamically update the cell value of an excel sheet with another excel sheet cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have two excel sheets, Test.xlsx and Sample.xlsx. I'm referring the "B10"cell value in the Test.xlsx with the "C10" of Sample.xlsx using the formula "='C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\Work[Sample.xlsx]Sheet1'!C10" in the B10 of Test.xlsx file. Now I opened Sample.xlsx, edited C10 cell value, Saved it and Closed. I then opened Test.xlsx and the cell value "B10" in the Test.xlsx will not update until I just re-open the Sample.xlsx. Is there any way to just open Sample.xlsx, edit the C10 value and close it so that the value of the cell B10 in Test.xlsx will update with out re-opening the Sample.xlsx file. Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I asked this question here after searching a lot in internet. Please let me know the answer if known. Degrading the points wont help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this using Excel 2010 and two .xlsx files.  With both files open (in the same instance of Excel, mind you), changing one and then switching to the other automatically shows the other with the change.

Then I tried what you said: Open source, make change, save and close, then open destination.  Same thing: the destination updated.  The only caveat is that I first needed to hit the Enable Content button in the destination.

Perhaps your Excel is set to manually update formulae?  In Excel 2010, it's on the Formulas ribbon, Calculation Options | Automatic.

Comment: Hello Sir, Thank you for your quick reply. I tried the options of enabling the contents and setting the Calculation options to Automatic. It did update  the external excel sheets sir. But my source excel is driven by a CAD system. I believe its a preference issue. Anyways Thanks for the replay.